# Верстка под 7" и Android 2.2

Tags: android

Здравствуйте

Требуется прописать отдельный стиль для разрешения 600х1024 и Android 2.2 и выше (для теста использую galaxy tab gt-p1010).

Хотел сделать через вставку параметра минимальной ширины для папки (т.е. например назвать папку `drawable-sw600dp`), но данный способ работает только начиная с Android 3.2.

Все делал по статье:
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Что посоветуете в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так начнем пожалуй :)

После долгих мучений решил данную проблему, но сначала маленький анализ и как вообще все делалось.

Для начала требовалось определить основные размеры экранов (см. таблицу в конце статьи указанной выше), вот приблизительно что получилось:

1. 240х320
2. 320х480, 640х960
3. 480х800, 480х854, 240х400, 240х432
4. 1024х600 (вот оно злополучное :))
5. 1280х800, 1280х720

И так для первой группы используем атрибуты small и notlong (помним что notlong это когда отношение меньшей стороны к большей лежит в пределах от 0.66 до 1 иначе long). Вторая группа это наш стантартный normal, но его я нигде не прописывал, т.е. это все стили, какртинки и лэйауты, которые берутся из папок без атрибутов. Третья группа используем тег long. Четвертая это large и sw600dp. Ну и пятая группа это xlarge и sw720dp. Подведем маленький итог:

1. small-notlong (т.е. папки называем darawable-small-notlong, layout-small-notlong, values-small-notlong);
2. normal или папки без атрибутов;
3. long;
4. large и sw600dp;
5. xlarge и sw720dp;

Мне кажется первые 3 пункта более или менее понятны (если нет задавайте вопросы, обязательно отвечу). Балее интересны 4 и 5 пункт. До версии 3.2 sw600dp и других атрибутов такова же вида не было, было лишь large и xlarge.

Так же опытным путем доказано что отображение к примеру 600х1024 под sdk 7 и 13 (это 3.2 :)) могут отличаются. Я сделал следующим образом, создал нужные мне папки с атрибуто large и xlarge, тем самым прописав стиль для версии от 7 или 8(т.е. android 2.1 и 2.2 и выше) и еще дополнительно папки с атрибутами sw600dp и sw720dp, которые начинают работать с версии sdk 13 (android 3.2). Т.е. атрибуты large и xlarge работают похожим образом, как и sw600dp и sw720dp, только для sdk 7-8 и выше. (ну пока что никто не жаловался, вроде все работает :)).

Все это дело проверил под несколько устройств с разными операционками и разрешениями все отображалось как и задумывалось. На этом все, спасибо за внимание. :)